# Elastic Search not indexing **some** of the documents

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a java application, which is indexing json documents into ElasticSearch. I have observed that some of the documents go "missing" i.e. when I query ElasticSearch I dont find the document. And, this is not a consistent behaviour. I am seeing some of the documents go fine.

I do not see any error in my application log (the indexing is in try-catch) OR even in the Elastic search log. Any thoughts on how to go about debugging this?

I am using JEST based client to connect to elasticsearch via io-searchbox utility. And, elastic search version is 1.3.6.

Comment: please provide the code you're using to index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be related to dynamic mapping feature of elastic search. So, the initial document which got indexed had a different data type than the new document. This resulted in elastic search not indexing the new document.

Comment: what will be the solution for such conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the elastic logs (\ELASTIC_HOME\elasticsearch-2.3.2\logs). It is giving very clear picture why your data is not getting indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes with 2.3.2. Column's with their DataType are unique in index file. For example if there is column "Salary" with datatype "string" and some other document same column "Salary" is coming with "numeric" datatype. ES will through exception and all the exceptions are caught in log files. And you will feel like documents are not indexed. If log files clearly checked you will get to know the root cause.